# Error C# get view with CouchBase

Tags: c#, couchbase

I have set of Document in Data Bucket like

```
{
   "article_id": "107668",
   "domain": "thethao.baobelung.ma",
   "category_alias": "thethao-menu1",
   "ip": "115.77.224.119",
   "process_time": "635416228108751043",
   "created_at": "2014072210"
}
```

My View:

Map

```
function (doc, meta) {
  if(doc.article_id &&doc.category_alias && doc.domain){
    emit([doc.article_id,doc.category_alias,doc.domain],1);
  }
}
```

Reduce, I use built-in function `_sum`
It's OK to execute results.

[_view/by_hour?group=true&connection_timeout=60000&limit=10&skip=0][1]

Results with group = true

```
{"rows":[
{"key":["100041","batdongsan-noi-that-nha-viet","m.batdongsan.baobelung.vn"],"value":1},
{"key":["100046","thethao-premier-league","thethao.baobelung.vn"],"value":1},
{"key":["100082","ban-doc-phap-luat","baobelung.vn"],"value":4},
{"key":["100116","van-hoa","m.baobelung.vn"],"value":1},
{"key":["100173","batdongsan-noi-that-nha-viet","m.batdongsan.baobelung.vn"],"value":2},
{"key":["100181","van-hoa","m.baobelung.vn"],"value":1},
{"key":["100195","van-hoa","m.baobelung.vn"],"value":1},
{"key":["100195","van-hoa","baobelung.vn"],"value":1},
{"key":["100272","batdongsan-noi-that-nha-viet","m.batdongsan.baobelung.vn"],"value":1},
{"key":["100274","batdongsan-noi-that-nha-viet","m.batdongsan.baobelung.vn"],"value":1}
]
}
```

But when I use C# to get view with option Group = True, then error:

> var view = clientDetail.GetView("trackingdetail",
>   "by_hour").Group(true);

```
Error converting value 1 to type 'Couchbase.IViewRow'. Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

Show me the way to get results to a List of Items?

Comment: I'm not familiar with couchbase.. but are you sure that Groups first parameter is a boolean and not an `IViewRow`?

Comment: Yeb, It's equipment with query string "group=true" above (call via HTTP API)

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your .net client libraries (SDK) to latest version first. And don't forget about latest Json encoder too...
Updating to latest version solve mostly same problem for me...

Comment: I'm using the latest version of .NET SDK and Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: You can use Fiddler to capture HTTP REST request/response to/from Couchbase to investigate the problem.